# Reading a text file in Matlab and calculating average of values

Tags: arrays, matlab, sum, average

I have created a text file which contains integer values such as follows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
56
10
.. and so on
```

The idea is to find the average of these numbers. I have done below but for some reason I am getting multiple outputs:

```
fid = fopen('random.txt', 'r');

data = fscanf(fid, '%i',1 );

fclose(fid);

averageValues= 'Average ' + (sum(data)/length(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

That call to `fscanf` will read only the first line of your file. You should place it in a loop to actually read every line, or simply use one of the followings

```
data = cell2mat(textscan(fid, '%d'));
data = dlmread('random.txt')
```

The error you get is also in the last line. In Matlab you can't convert doubles into strings in that way. The correct code is

```
avg = mean(data);
disp(['Average = ' num2str(avg)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all data in one line of code:

```
data=textread('d:\1.txt','%d');
datamean=mean(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data = textread('random.txt',%i);
 mean_data = mean(data);
```

%i is used because you have integer values. If you have double values, change it to %d.

Answer (score 0):

No to all answers. If your .txt file only consists of numbers, just do

```
>> load file.txt  
>> mean(ans)
```

Example:

```
>> system('cat test.txt')
1
4
4
6
ans =

     0

>> load test.txt
>> mean(test)

ans =

                      3.75
```